# Parameterization of the Costa-Hoffman-Meeks surface

Tags: special-functions, parametrization, elliptic-functions

I developed a library for the evaluation of some special functions such as the Weierstrass elliptic functions. I like to add some pictures to illustrate it, and this allows to check that the library works fine. For example, the Costa surface, which is parameterized with the help of the Weierstrass $\wp$-function and the Weierstrass $\zeta$ function:

[image]

I found a generalization of this surface on the web: the [Costa-Hoffman-Meeks surface](https://virtualmathmuseum.org/Surface/costa-h-m/costa-h-m.html), I'd like to plot it but I didn't find its parameterization. Would you know a parameterization of this surface?

Comment: your link shows four relevant articles from the late 1980's to early 1990's. Three are by Karcher, here is a long one: https://virtualmathmuseum.org/Surface/minimal_surface_construction_karcher.html

Comment: https://www.msri.org/publications/sgp/jim/geom/minimal/library/costa/index.html    Jim Hoffman was at MSRI for some time; he had been responsible for programming minimal surfaces for David Hoffman. David Hoffman spent at least one year at msri.

Comment: Thanks. I already checked this link. It provides a C++ file but it depends on other files that I didn't find. Thanks for the first link too.

Comment: https://minimal.sitehost.iu.edu/archive/HigherGenus/Higher/CostaHoffmanMeeks-1/web/index.html

Comment: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-21/issue-1/A-complete-embedded-minimal-surface-in-bf-Rsp-3-with/10.4310/jdg/1214439467.full  This is the Costa surface, I don't know how detailed they were in later papers about your parametrization

Comment: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-994-seminar-in-geometry-fall-2004/99ad614fbf2c72b284b15e7f29fd5854_David.pdf  This one seems promising, the author went to the trouble of parametrizing the surfaces,  possibly making computer graphics